# How do I pack AND USE a packed font on my C# project

Tags: c#, fonts

I've built a very simple application to use on my friend's print shop, and I'd like to pack some fonts that I have on my computer with it. I've already added the fonts to the project folder but I don't know how to use them from there. If someone could teach me a not so complicated way to do that, I'd be very, very thankful.

PS.: I know I can install the font on my friend's PC and simply run the program, but I'd rather learn how to do it properly

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good article about packaging fonts: 
http://www.matevarga.com/articles/software/embedding-fonts-windows-forms/

And another from MSDN for WPF apps.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I'm really new to c#, and the MSDN page has some codes I've never seen before on c#. I'm really thankful for the help, but isn't there a more...simple way to do this? The fisrt article is from 2009, using .net 2.0

(Please, I'm just aking, not criticizing you help or anything like that. I really don't want to offend you in any way :c )

Comment: The simple way is how you described in your OP. Just install it on any computers that need it. The proper way is to package it as described in those 2 articles.

Comment: I see...so, is there a way to create a installer that already install the font and any other resources I'll eventually need?

Comment: There are two methods, use an install package or use the runtime environment to install the fonts. Both are described below:

http://www.brutaldev.com/post/2009/03/26/Installing-and-removing-fonts-using-C